# Index of the Fredholm operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators, fredholm-operators

I have two vector bundles $E_1$, $E_2$ over $M$ and an embedding of the smooth sections $\lambda : \Gamma(M, E_1) \rightarrow \Gamma(M, E_1 \oplus E_2)$. I consider a Fredholm differential operator $D_1 : \Gamma(M, E_1) \rightarrow \Gamma(M, E_1)$ which can easily be lifted to the Fredholm differential operator $D_2 : \Gamma(M, E_1 \oplus E_2) \rightarrow \Gamma(M, E_1 \oplus E_2)$. What can be said about their indices $\mathrm{Ind}(D_1)$ and $\mathrm{Ind}(D_2)$?

Comment: could  you please  more  explain how do you deduce  $D_2$  from $D_1$? Moreover is $\lambda$ the  obvious  embedding?Or you fix an arbitrary embedding?Finally can  you explain what is the  motivation for this question?